# How to pass an argument to a function passed to mapPartitions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to use `mapPartitions` function instead of using `map`, the problem is that I want to pass an `Array` as an argument, but `mapPartitions` does not take `Array` as an argument. How can I pass the array as argument?

```
mapPartitions[U: ClassTag](
    f: Iterator[T] => Iterator[U], preservesPartitioning: Boolean = false)
```

Comment: Are you trying to access data in the array within the `mapPartitions`? If so, you could simply broadcast the array as a variable.

Comment: Could you either [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or explain why it doesn't work for you so it can be improved? You also have quite a few you other question with answer just asking for being accepted. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

It is not clear what you're asking so I am going to guess that you have a function that looks more or less like this:

```
def foo(iter: Iterator[T], xs: Array[V]): Iterator[U] = ???
```

and you want to pass it to `mapPartitions`.

You have three options:

1. Use an anonymous function:

   ```
   val xs: Array[V] = ???
   val rdd: RDD[U] = ???

   rdd.mapPartitions(iter => foo(iter, xs))
   ```
2. Rewrite `foo` to support currying:

   ```
   def foo(xs: Array[V])(iter: Iterator[T]): Iterator[U] = ??? // Rest as before

   rdd.mapPartitions(foo(xs))
   ```
3. Curry `foo` like this:

   ```
   val bar = (iter: Iterator[T]) => foo(iter, xs))

   rdd.mapPartitions(bar)
   ```

Comment: I just encountered what seems to be the same limitation as what this question (or rather answer) seem to deal with. I tried the line of thought implied in this answer and made a clearer question of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61527641/1509695).